# handleSubmit react hook form do not working, its do not execute onSumbmit

Tags: reactjs

onSubmit does not executed and I do not know what is problem , its execute without handleSumbit but I need it for get all data from form.
I think I have done everything necessary for this form but its do not working.
I need help?

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const LoginPage = () =>{

const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const onSubmit = (data) => (
    alert(JSON.stringify(data))
);
  
return(
    <section className="section-login">
        <div className="login__header">
            <img src={anarLogo} className="login__header--logo" alt="header logo" />
        </div>
        <form className='login__form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Input
                register={register} 
                inputName='User name'
                inputType='text'
                inputClass='form__input--text' 
                inputPlaceholder='Username'
                // inputErrors = {errors}
                inputLabel = 'username'
                rules={{ required: true, maxLength: 20, min: 3 }}
            />
            <Input 
                register={register}
                inputName='Password'
                inputType='password'
                inputClass='form__input--password'
                inputPlaceholder='Password'
                // inputErrors = {errors}
                inputLabel = 'password'
                rules={{ required: true, maxLength: 20, min: 3 }}
            />
            <button type='submit'></button>
        </form>
    </section>
  )
 }
```

my input file :

```
 const Input = ({register, inputName, inputType, inputClass, inputPlaceholder, inputLabel, 
     rules,}) => {


return(
    <div className='form__input'>
        <input
        {...register(inputLabel , {...rules})}
        name={inputName}
        type={inputType} 
        className={`input ${inputClass}`} 
        placeholder={ inputPlaceholder }
        />
    </div>
 )
}

export default Input;
```

Comment: You assign the `onSubmit` event the return value of `handleSubmit(onSubmit)`, which makes no sense, since `onSubmit` expects to be assigned a function, what you probably trying to achieve is `onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)}`, this will correctly execute your `handleSubmit` function when submitting

Comment: The [`handleSubmit()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit/) function does return a function.

Comment: ```onSubmit={(e) => {validateErrors();handleSubmit(onSubmit)(e);}}```  is what worked for me. notice the currying

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`register()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) function returns an object with a `name` property. In your input file, you are overwriting the `name` that it provides (see the line directly below the one where the result of `register()` is spread onto `<input>`). This is causing the form to fail the validation rules that you set. The first argument of [`handleSubmit()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit) does not get called unless validation is successful.

Comment: your last sentence was so important, and led me to find my issue. The first argument of handleSubmit() does not get called unless validation is successful.  onSubmit is not working? check all your validation rules!

Answer (score 2):

only change place register to last like:

```
      <input
        name={inputName}
        type={inputType} 
        className={`input ${inputClass}`} 
        placeholder={ inputPlaceholder }
        {...register(inputLabel , {...rules})}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

The other approach is just setting `noValidate` on your form tag if you don't need form validation (i.e. radio button group).